# apply numpy functions array to an array of elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to get a an array generated from applying differnt functions all stored in a numpy array on the same parameter, is there an efficient way coding this using numpy?

```
    #func_array- a numpy array of different functions that get the same parameter
    #X - parameter for evey function in func_array
    def aplly_all(func_array, X):
        return func_array(X)
    #where return value is an array where index i has the value - func_array[i](X)
```

the only solution i thought of is iterating through the func_array and i wonder if there is a faster way of doing it

Comment: Use a list of functions, and list comprehension to apply them to the parameter(s), creating a new list of values.

Answer (score 0):

I once had the exact same questions, and this is what I was told:
The vectorization speed-up that numpy array operations provide is due to the base data-types defined for the array (say an *array of floats*, for instance).
When the array elements are objects, this advantage is mostly nullified. Since functions are objects, `func_array` is an array of objects. Thus any other method will hardly provide any speedup over iteration.

This is what I've learnt. I'm open to more experienced advice.